# Login and send form not working with requests

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I've written code for a programming mission 2 on **hackthissite**, just some fun and to practice coding etc. I have completed the mission, but I was unable to get Python to login using the `requests` library and upload my code to the form automatically.

Here is a snippet from my code with the code that is not working and still says *"you need to login"* in page content:

```
def upload_code(key):
    login_url = 'https://www.hackthissite.org/user/login'
    btn_submit = 'Login'
    username = 'example_username'
    password = 'example_password'
    login = {
        'btn_submit': btn_submit,
        'password': password,
        'username': username,
    }

    session = requests.session()
    header_auth = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko',
        'referer': 'www.hackthissite.org/user/login'
    }
    auth = session.post(login_url, headers=header_auth, data=login)

    challange_url = 'https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2/index.php'
    header = {'referer': 'www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2/index.php'}
    data = {'solution': key}

    r = session.post(challange_url, headers=header, data=data, verify=True)
    print(r.content)
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set cookies.

I've tried in many ways to get cookies from the site, but it seems that it gives invalid cookies.

However, you can open *Network* in your browser (If you're using Chrome, press Cntrl+E, if you're using Firefox, press Cntrl+Shift+E), then visit the [login page](https://www.hackthissite.org/user/login) to find a valid PHPSESSID cookie of the request to *login* in *Cookies*.

Then you can paste PHPSESSID cookie value in the code below:

```py
from requests import Session

login_url = "https://www.hackthissite.org/user/login"
page_url = "https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2/index.php"

PHPSESSID = f"PHPSESSID=2r4t6qg89b8k89b871q4b6q5i3" # Cookie example. Enter yours.

login_headers = {
    "Host": "www.hackthissite.org",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Referer": "https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2/index.php",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Cookie": PHPSESSID,
    "Content-Length": "62",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "DNT": "1",
}

login_data = {
    "username": "Your username",
    "password": "Your password",
    "btn_submit": "Login",
}



page_headers = {
    "Host": "www.hackthissite.org",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Referer": "https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2/index.php",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cookie": "PHPSESSID=2r4t6qg8eb8j89b871q4b6q0i3",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "DNT": "1",
}

page_data = {
    "solution": "Dontevenknow",
}

with Session() as session:
    session.post(login_url, headers=login_headers, data=login_data)
    response = session.post(page_url, headers=page_headers, data=page_data)

    print("Authenticated:", "Login Required" not in response.text)
```

It works fine for me, I tested with both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Its late rite now, but will try this out tomorrow and let you know,  thanks. I did try cookies that day i posted this question in the end and i got logged in but would go to the last page i had visited and would not then go to another page for me to post to a form...so i half got there. i will try this script out tomorrow, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry forgot, Just got it working now had to change the cookie in other header too which did not have a comment next too it saying, was saying Authenticated: False, BUT now its all working and says - Authenticated: True :) Thanks.

Comment: Also just a quick one the two headers, they are both the same really you only need the one? i just tried it using one(the login headers for both POST requests) and it worked fine, same cookies etc.

Comment: delete last comment, just checked again...does not work using the same headers.Also why do i need to of the same sort of headers, i tried using one of them twice for both POST requests and it did not work, could you explain to me why that code works? also when i print content of both the first still says you need to log in which is weird but second says hello username etc I'm logged in.